# On graphs of congruent polynomials modulo $x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This isn't homework, and I already have an answer, but I wanted to get input as to whether or not I've solved the question.  It reads

> If $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $f(x) \equiv g(x) \, (\text{mod } x)$, then what can be said about the graphs of $y = f(x)$ and $y = g(x)$?

Here is what I have.  Since $f(x) \equiv g(x) \, (\text{mod } x)$, we have that $f(x) = g(x) + x k(x)$ for some $k(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.  The only real observation I can see from this is that $f(0) = g(0)$.  Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Nothing missing. The reason is that your observation is also a sufficient condition. If $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, then $f(x)-g(x)$ is multiple of $x$.

Comment: It wants a better title.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Suggestions? I have an answer for the question, so posting the question itself would be inappropriate.  The actual question I have is that I am not sure what the question wants ... so that's what I made the title.

Comment: What about **On graphs of congruent polynomials**?